# Image max crop percentage

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm building an responsive Image gallery using flexbox.
I want to make it respect aspect ratios, and still aim a 100% page with.
The term page in this case is equal to the parent container.

**Parameters I want:**

- Aim for page with of 100% (exept don't force it if a image is upright and will be forced to crop more than 35% of the image)
- If widescreen/landscape try to scale it to max-page width and still respect to not crop more than 35% of the image horizontal or vertical in total.
- Max row height of around 25vh
  -All rows don't need to have equal heights.

**Problem**

It's always cropping images way too much. So the main content is often not visible.
How can I avoid cropping it more than a defined percentage?

**My approach so far:**

```
<div className="App">
      <div className="gallery__container">
        {images.map((i) => (
          <div className="gallery__image__container">
            <img className="gallery__image" src={i} alt="ginger" />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
.gallery__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.gallery__image__container {
  height: 25vh;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
}

.gallery__image {
  max-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

**To clarify my problem I made a simplified example code sandbox:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-spence-4qtc3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Maybe there is a pure css solution, but this seems like a job for javascript (but it's not tagged like that)

Comment: Thank you added, javascript and reactjs. A solution in javascript would make me even more comfortable I guess :)

Comment: not sure, but is it simply or closer to what you looked for : https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-banach-khill (without looking at the ratio ) .

Comment: Can't find any difference in your sandbox. What did you change? For example, the image with the hair strain alone is an upright image and still scaled and cropped to full width.

Comment: looks like update did not nwork. modif were : `.gallery__image {height: 100%;width:100%;object-fit: cover;object-position:35% 17% ;}`  for the ratio , there is aspect-ratio you could use/test   alike : `aspect-ratio: 20 / 15 ;` but since portrait and landscape are mixed, JS should be used to choose which ratio to use or clamp on the same line similar ratios to keep coherent cropping. (remenber people will mostly land on the page with their own media and won't play with the screen-size, . object-position and or ratio should choose according to the media so it shows what you want the most).